# Is this sentence correct? Tanya is a team member who holds expertise in chat support

Tags: grammar, sentence, articles

Tanya is a team member who holds expertise in chat support.

I'm in a doubt specifically about whether it should have 'the' in place of 'a'. Feel free to notify other mistakes as well.

Comment: Is Tanya the only team member that has expertise in chat support?

Comment: one has expertise, one does not hold it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Tanya is the team member who holds expertise in chat support* very strongly suggests that Tanya is the *only* team member with that expertise while *Tanya is a team member who holds expertise in chat support* suggests that other team members may have the same expertise.

The whole sentence is a little clunky, though syntactically acceptable and (save for *the/a*) entirely clear.  I'd prefer the simple *has* to *holds*, perhaps *Tanya is the team member who has expertise in chat support.*

Comment: There is no suggestion to me with _a_ that other team members have the same expertise – only that Tanya has it. The others are not commented upon at all; they may all have the same expertise, or none of them may have it.

Comment: Tanya is our chat support expert on the team.